# Angular ' ' is not assignable to type 'unknown[]'. error

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular 'PriceRuleApi' is not assignable to type 'unknown[]'. The error points on the line this.dataSource.data with the error 'PriceRuleApi' is not assignable to type 'unknown[]'. Any idea?

## Interface

```
export interface PriceRuleApi {
    pricerule: any;
    success: boolean,
    data: PriceRule[],
    total: number,
    pageSize: number,
    page: number
}
```

## data source

```
dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
```

## data

```
{_id: "5d9564c336651b0f50bf3e66", name: "Rule 1", __v: 0, books: Array(2)}
```

## code snippet

```
 map(data => {

                    this.isLoading = false;
                    this.isTotalReached = false;
                    console.log("gg" , data)
                    // this.totalItems = data
                    return data;
                }),
                catchError(() => {
                    this.isLoading = false;
                    this.isTotalReached = true;
                    return observableOf([]);
                })
            ).subscribe(data => this.dataSource.data = data);
```

## model

```
export interface PriceRule {
    _id: number,
    name: string,
    books: Array<string>
}
```

Comment: What was logged by console.log("gg" , data)?

Comment: its fix already sir thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MatTableDataSource.data` expects an array, but it seems like the `data` variable you have is just a single `PriceRuleApi`. It should be `PriceRuleApi[]` or `PriceRule[]` perhaps, whatever data correspond to the rows you'd like to display

`MatTableDataSource` is an array of rows, effectively, and so it expects your data to be a collection of these rows.

Comment: you mean  data: PriceRule[ to  data: PriceRuleApi?[],

Comment: If you mouseover your 'data', you'll see what type it is. It should be `PriceruleApi`. But that's not an array. The question for you is what kind of table is your `this.dataSource` trying to display? Whatever that corresponds to should be an array.

Comment: was able to fix  it         return this.http.get<PriceRuleApi[]>(CONSTANST.routes.pricerule.list, { params: params });